# Location coordinates representation

Tags: machine-learning, cosine-similarity, recommendation-engine

What is the best way to represent longitude and latitude when calculating the similarities between items?

Basically, I'm trying to do cosine similarity between multiple items. In addition to the typical features and metadata, I want to include the longitude and latitude somehow. This way when recommending items the location should be taken into consideration.

Any ideas please.

Answer (score -1):

Use the geographic distance between the points

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance